# I need to use remove every thing before and after a variable string in notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++, preg-replace

Hopefully, someone can help me with this. I have a text file that has a list of RSS URLs in XML format on multiple lines. The text file would look like this:

```
<outline type="rss" text="Tech Viral" title="Tech Viral" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechViral" htmlUrl="https://techviral.net"/>
<outline type="rss" text="The Verge" title="The Verge" xmlUrl="http://www.theverge.com/rss/full.xml" htmlUrl="https://www.theverge.com/"/>
<outline type="rss" text="Joystiq" title="Joystiq" xmlUrl="http://www.joystiq.com/rss.xml" htmlUrl="https://www.engadget.com/rss.xml"/>
<outline type="rss" text="BGR" title="BGR" xmlUrl="http://www.boygeniusreport.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://bgr.com"/>
```

I want to get rid of everything before :

```
xmlUrl="
```

and everything after:

```
"
```

So the final output would look like this:

```
http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechViral
http://www.theverge.com/rss/full.xml
http://www.joystiq.com/rss.xml
http://www.boygeniusreport.com/feed/
```

Basically, I just want the feed URLs in the file on a line left. Can anyone help with that? I am using Notepad++ on Windows but if there is another software that will do this easier then regular expressions, I'll take any suggestions that get the job done.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the need for fancy

Find `(?m)^.*xmlUrl="([^"]*)".*`
Replace `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Use look behid (`?<=`):

[`(?<=xmlUrl=")[^"]+`](https://regex101.com/r/9vQKc9/1)

will match anything followed by `xmlUrl="` until the next quote `"`.